# JSON oData.metadata

Tags: json, odata

I have questions about JSON returning from the server using the Microsoft oData API.
Cannot figure it out.

Query1:

```
http://localhost:63717/odata/City(1)
```

Fiddler returns the raw data below.
Everything is in its own brackets.

```
{
  "odata.metadata":"http://localhost:63717/odata/$metadata#City/@Element","CityID":1,"CityName":"Minnetonka","CityAddr1":null,"CityAddr2":null,"CityCity":null,"CityState":null,"CityZip":null,"CityPhone":null,"CityFAX":null,"CityExtent":"-93.53,44.88,-93.39,44.93","CityHeaderImage":null
}
```

Query2:

```
http://localhost:63717/odata/City?$filter=CityName eq 'Minnetonka'
```

Fiddler returns the raw data below.
Data is in two sets of bracketed data

```
{
  "odata.metadata":"http://localhost:63717/odata/$metadata#City","value":[
    {
      "CityID":1,"CityName":"Minnetonka","CityAddr1":null,"CityAddr2":null,"CityCity":null,"CityState":null,"CityZip":null,"CityPhone":null,"CityFAX":null,"CityExtent":"-93.53,44.88,-93.39,44.93","CityHeaderImage":null
    }
  ]
}
```

What do I have to do to format my JSON coming back for $filters in the oData request?
That odata.metadata is killing me in Query2.
Please explain what I am doing wrong.

Comment: In the second example, the `value` property in result is showing an array of `City` types (a listing of one or more objects). `[ ... ]` denotes an array in JavaScript. In the first example, you have just one `City` element. The path shown in the `odata.metadata` property value describes the structure of the element being returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example, you have just one `City` element (denoted by `City(1)` in the request and `#City/@Element` in the result path).

In the second example, the `value` property in result is showing an array of `City` types (a listing of one or more objects). `[ ... ]` denotes an array in JavaScript. For a `$filter` type query, this is what I would expect. You can also see that the response path is less specific (`#City` instead of `#City/@Element`).

The path shown in the `odata.metadata` property value describes the structure of the element being returned, as I showed two examples above. The format of the return data will change depending on how you request it.

If you're having trouble parsing the JSON returned, consider using a library to do the heavy lifting for you. For example:

- [datajs](http://datajs.codeplex.com/)
- [JayData](http://jaydata.org/)
- [Breeze.js](http://www.breezejs.com/home)

<sup>[[Source](http://www.odata.org/libraries/)]</sup>

Comment: @SCB: Thanks, I listed all of the JavaScript libraries from that source and the source itself.

Comment: Thanks Cory and All: Now that I know I am returning many results in Query2, what would be your next step to get that data into a JavaScript grid control? Query1 data goes in fine. Not so much with Query2. Any comments helpful.

Comment: @kanderson: I would ask that as a separate question. In it, show what you've tried and what's not working. Reference this question if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks Cory!
datajs was the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong, the two formats actually represent two different forms of result.

The first you are requesting a single item as you are specifying the key for the entity.

In the second you are potentially asking for a list of entities. The Odata.Metadata is separate in this response otherwise it would be repeated for every item returned and would be a waste in terms of content length.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way that you are addressing the entity.

With //localhost:63717/odata/City(1) you are addressing one entity ("/entityset/key"). You will always return back one City (if one exists). There is no need for it to return an array because it will never return more than one.

With //localhost:63717/odata/City you are addressing a collection of entities ("/entityset"). 0 to n City entities could be returned, hence the need for a collection.